# Post javascript generated select option

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc

Here's the code in the view:

```
<select id="SelectOptions"></select>
```

And here's the javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/PriseRendezVous/GetDispos/',
    data: { dateText: selected },
    success: function (listDispos) {
        var myArray = listDispos.split(',');
        for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
            $('#SelectOptions').append('<option value="' + myArray[i] + '">' + myArray[i] + '</option>');
        }
     }
});
```

Say that the `Model` is of type `Car`. I want to post the selected value as `Car.Color`.

How can I associate the value with my `Model` property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at how `DropDownListFor` renders HTML, assume your view looks something like this (assume you have a `ColorSelectList` property on your Car model that is of type `SelectList` that contains SelectListItems of all of your colors):

```
@model Car
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Color, Model.ColorSelectList)
```

Your HTML would come out looking something like this:

```
<select id="Color" name="Color">
    <option value="Blue" selected="selected">Blue</option>
    <option value="Red">Red</option>
</select>
```

So when you `POST` the form to your controller, it should be expecting your model:

```
public JsonResult GetDispos(Car car) { ... }
```

Then, the `DefaultModelBinder` will take your values and translate them based on the names of the properties in your form to the object in your action method.

So you simply need to give the names of the elements in your form the corresponding names in your model's property. To find out more about this, search for information on model binders, and in particular, [`DefaultModelBinder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.defaultmodelbinder%28v=vs.118%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The MVC model binder works by matching the name attribute associated with an HTML input to properties of the Model it is expecting to receive.

So you'd need to build your select like:

```
<select id="SelectOptions" name="Color"></select>
```

However, HTML helpers will do all the work for you:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Color, new List<SelectListItem>())
```

will generate:

```
<select id="Color" name="Color"></select>
```